# Image not showing up in ImageView after using Image Picker

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, imagepicker

I am trying to write a simple app that will update the ImageView with a photo from my photos library. I can open the photos library and select a photo, but after I do that the default image in the ImageViewer does not show up. Any idea why?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var photoView: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func testGesture(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

       let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }

        photoView.image = selectedImage
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Careful when you copy-paste code.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`'s `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method. Remove the `private` and modify the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method to the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method syntax and you're good to go.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    photoView.image = selectedImage
    print(selectedImage)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```